# Drupal: add drag and drop ordering for CCK fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there any way in Drupal to add drag and drop ordering functionality to CCK fields in a specific node ?

My customer would like sometimes to change the order of the items for some nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the order for different nodes. You can only change the order across the node type.

Otherwise, you have to come up with sorting rules based on values and program it all in.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called Arange Fields:
http://drupal.org/project/arrange_fields

> This module lets you drag-and-drop the fields of any CCK content type, Webform, or almost any other form in Drupal into the positions you would like for editing. This makes it super simple to have forms with inline fields, which you can change at any point. Tab indexing is also updated, so no matter how you arrange the fields, the users can still tab through them easily. And, you can now add arbitrary bits of HTML markup-- labels, images, HR's, etc.